# Why does this window open when I plot something in spyder?

Tags: python-3.x, spyder

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NN5Dx.png)

Not sure what this window is next to spyder and what it does nor why it opens up.

Answer (score 1):

See [Spyder plots in separate windows](http://Spyder%20plots%20in%20separate%20windows)

The window is just Spyder's external plotting window. You can change how plots are displayed on Spyder in the preferences tab.